# Newton-Rhapson method for a multivariate function

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, newton-raphson

I have a system

$\textbf{0}= f_n(\textbf{x})+ \epsilon u_n(\textbf{x})$,

which I want to solve numerically, where

$\textbf{x}=[x_1, ...,x_n]^T$ and $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$.

What is the Newton-Rhapson formula for this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#k_variables.2C_k_functions

Comment: What have you tried so far? Read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) before asking.

Comment: I have solved it already! :)

Comment: Thats good news. It would be great, if you could formulate an answer to your question. (In general, answering your own question is a good thing on StackExchange.) This will help other people looking for the same problem. (Also your question will get some upvotes.)